# Creating a table with date and time as rows and having "tasks" that match these entries

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, repeater

I hope to is possible to explain, so here goes! In C# and ASP.NET I want to make a table which shows me which tasks there there is on which days and at what time with say 2 hours span. To illustrate this, I'll try to draw it below:

```
Date              Role 1     Role 2     Role n…
01-11-2013 00:00    
01-11-2013 02:00    
01-11-2013 04:00    
01-11-2013 06:00    
01-11-2013 08:00  Task 1
01-11-2013 10:00  Task 1
01-11-2013 12:00  Task 1
01-11-2013 14:00  Task 1
01-11-2013 16:00             Task 2
01-11-2013 18:00             Task 2
01-11-2013 20:00             Task 2
01-11-2013 22:00    
02-11-2013 00:00    
02-11-2013 02:00    
02-11-2013 04:00    
02-11-2013 06:00    
02-11-2013 08:00                        Task 3
02-11-2013 10:00                        Task 3
02-11-2013 12:00                        Task 3
02-11-2013 14:00                        Task 3
02-11-2013 16:00                        Task 3
02-11-2013 18:00                        Task 3
02-11-2013 20:00    
02-11-2013 22:00    
03-11-2013 00:00
03-11-2013 02:00    
03-11-2013 04:00    
...
```

So behind I'll have the data in an SQL Server database, but what I'm not really sure about is how to create the table. I'm thinking of using ASP.NET Repeaters, maybe nested, maybe 2 datasources where as 1 is the date and time and the other adds where there's a match? What is the "hard part" at least for me, is how to create rows where there is no match?

Any help is appreciated as I'm not that strong in coding anymore! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prefer repeaters to other more complex ASP.net controls unless there is something from say a listview or gridview that you will need.

To create rows where there is no match - Start with a list of dates/times and bind your repeater to this. By the looks of things you want a repeater for the Role headings, and a repeater for each column in the table. i.e:

```
<tr>
  <td>Date</td>
  <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rptHeadings">
    <td><%# Eval("Role") %>
  </asp:Repeater>
</tr>
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rptDateTimes" OnItemDataBound="rptDateTimes_DataBound">
  <tr>
    <td><%# Eval("Date") %>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rptTasks" OnItemDataBound="rptTasks_DataBound">
    <td>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" id="litTask" />
    </td>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </tr>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And then in your codebehind - handle the rptDateTimes_DataBound event to bind your rptTasks repeater, and handle the rptTasks_DataBound event to populate the Text property of litTask - if there is a task then set the text otherwise leave it blank. Example:

```
protected void rptTasks_DataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem) return;

  if (/* logic to determine if task is done At given date by given role */)
  {
    litTask.Name = SomeTask.Name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for example:

SQL table:

Role | From | Till

Firstly, get all the amount of rows via a group by and place these into a List of Roles

You then already have your columns (datetime + n* Role)

Create a datatable for datetime and roles.

```
datatable dt = new datatable();
dt.Columns.add("DateTime", typeof(datetime));
foreach(var j in roles)
{
 dt.columns.add(j);
}
```

Then select the min and max date (or only all the dates from today), say you want every hour or half hour between that, create a loop for that amount.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++) //this is the hourly notation
{
  datarow dr = new datarow();
  dr["Datetime"] = new datetime(year, month, day, i,0,0)
  for(int j = 0; j < roles.count; i++) // this is the role 
  {
    // here comes the selection logic for that row, NULL if nothing else is available
    dr[roles[j]] = something;
  }

  dt.rows.add(dr);
}
```

//change something into your logic for where to get the data from, the double for loop will create a row with data in each column. When no data would be available, simple give a NULL.

i hope this logic can already get you further